# How to skip a part of the code if a certain condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, primes, brute-force

As I am getting more and more comfortable with writing scripts in Python I wrote a script that finds prime numbers by trying to divide each number in a range in each number (kinda like Brute Force haha).
It works but I wanted to make the process faster and more efficient.

My code:

```py
count = 0

for i in range(2,1000):
    j = 2
    while j < 1000:
        if i%j==0:
            count = count + 1
        j = j + 1
    if count == 1:
        print(i)
    count = 0
```

Explanation:

I check and store in `count` how many time does a number can be divided.
If by the end of the check `count` equals 1 that means that the number is prime (gets divided only by itself).

**What I want now** is to stop the process of checking how many times the number can get divided when the "count" variable exceed 1 (2 or more). How do I do that?

I wanted to do something with `try` and `except` but didn't know what...

Comment: have you tried `break`?

Comment: Please never, ever use try/except for handling the flow of your application, or for breaking out of a loop. They're for handling errors, not for defining the execution flow of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Add an extra condition in here, and `break` out of the loop if the count is greater than one. Put this inside the `while` loop:

```
if i % j == 0:
  count += 1
  if count > 1:
      break
```

As mentioned in the comments, it's cleaner to just use `count` as part of the loop condition. Here's an improved version:

```
for i in range(2, 1000):
    j = 2
    count = 0
    while j <= i and count < 2:
        if i % j == 0:
            count += 1
        j += 1
    if count == 1:
        print(i)
```

Of course, there are faster ways to find if a number is prime - in particular, in the inner loop you should not iterate until `1000`, not even until `i` is reached, just until the `sqrt(i)`, but I'll leave that as an improvement for you to make ;)

Comment: Hey thank you! it worked. I tried using break but for some reason it ended the entire skript.

Comment: Would it not be better to put the condition inside the while and then not have a break at all?

Comment: Beware **break** is an implicit **goto** and leads to unmaintainable code. Changing **while** condition is better

Comment: @RobRaymond Yeah, that is what I was getting at.

Comment: Ok @EdwinCruz and RobRaymond, I updated my answer with your suggestions ;)

Comment: And I partially disagree, a `break` used with care can be readable and useful. Not for this particular case, though.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Yeah, I have always steered far from ```breaks``` and ```continues``` at all cost, only use them if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `break`. What `break` does is that it skips the remaining part of the loop and jumps to the statement following the loop.

```
count = 0
for i in range(2,1000):
    j = 2
    while j < 1000:
        if i%j==0:
            count = count + 1
            break
        j = j + 1   ### line 8
    if count == 1:
        print(i)
        
    count = 0
```

In this code, when python encounters break, it skips the remaining part of the loop (that is, the remaining loop is not executed) and jumps straight to the next statement, which is line 8

Answer (score 0):

#### Its all wrong, first you have to understand the algorithm to check for prime, basically a number is prime if it can't be fully divided by any number between 2 to (number//2)-1

*Now in your question, you couldn't use break anywhere, bcz you first searching for all divisible and then checking prime, better I'm adding a sample code to your problem which is more feasible to find primes*

### Code

```
number = int(input("Enter A Number"))
for i in range(2,number//2+1):      #See range arguments
    if(number%i==0):
        print("Not A Prime")
        break          #Break loop when condition reached
```